# How would a "Live" event on chat work out?

Tags: discussion

I see on other SE sites, there have "Live Events" on their chats. I've seen on other sites where they have these events with great success. It would come down to two things (in my approximation) which would affect the outcome:

1. Advertising the event (sticky up front?)
2. What the event might be in the first place

What I'm looking for are two things from you:

- What would a good event be?
- Your opinion on whether you think this would be a good idea or not.

I'm open to any other ideas you all might have, like how long a live event might be as well. Since I'm currently the owner of the chat, I can set up a live event ... realistically I really don't know what that means! I've not participated in a live event, nor do I know what it truly means to set one up.

We have a pretty good group of users for The Pitstop, so I think we could probably put a group together and make it a good live event. Let me know what you are thinking and we'll go from there. Thanks and I'm looking forward to your input!

Answer (score 1):

**It's an interesting idea**

There are many live events but the timing of them would potentially exclude some users located in particular points on the globe depending on the location and timing of the live event.  Some events span the entire tire, such as endurance racing.  Other events don't have a live feed in the US, WRC rally comes to mind.

Some race series that may have an audience regardless of time of day.

- Formula 1 - Premier global race series of bespoke cars
- MotoGP - Premier global race series of bespoke motorcycles
- WRC Rally - Premier global rally series
- NASCAR - Races most every weekend
- WEC - Premier endurance racing championship which includes the Le Mans 24 Hour event

There are a plethora of less well known but extraordinarily exciting race series that are out there but I imagine that the chances of finding people invested in those race series would be considerably lower than above.

- British Superbike
- British Touring Car
- IRL - Indy Racing League.  Chevy and Honda ICE driven spec chassis with a little aero work allowed.
- World Superbike
- World Touring Car
- DTM - Deutch Touring Masters (This is a great series)
- US Superbike - They just changed ownership of the series.  It's called something lame now.
- Rolex Series - US Domestic with the GT1 and 2 technical rules matching the WEC (Le Mans) technical rules so cars can get shipped and compete there if they qualify.

.....and the list goes on to things like the Dakar witch last over 3 weeks and doesn't have good feeds that are globally consistent.

Other than racing I can't think of anything off the top of my head that could be a scheduled event for gear heads.  I'm a fanatic so, there's that.  I watch no matter what, as much as I can consume.  Mostly on a DVR so I can slam through all of the junk.

One of the challenges I already alliterated.  When it's 10AM at Monza in Italy it's 2AM in San Francisco, I think.  Anyway, that's the challenge.  The good news on that front is that F1 and MotoGP hop around the globe.  A race in Melbourne, then China, the US, England, Italy and so on....so the timing of the viewing hops around.  The other good thing about MotoGP and F1 is that they are broadcast live around the world in most markets.  Something to think about at least.

Comment: What would you think about doing a live event with a YouTube video we all watch together and then have a comment/question/answer session either in real time or directly after? I can think of several series we could watch and that would be more time considerate. MCM, Hot Rod Garage, Engineering Explained, Obsessed Motor Sports, and Engine Masters are just a few.